# Updating multiple instances of eloquent model by looping an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a Quiz model that represents the following table:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lesson_id   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| explanation | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And another model QuizAnswer:

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title          | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_correct_ans | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quiz_id        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Think of this answer as a single choice out of 5 choices. Each of this 5 answers belongs to a quiz, one of which is correct answer. When I store a quiz, I also save the answers (and whether it is_correct_answer or not) at the same time in the store() method of QuizController:

```
    public function store(QuizRequest $request)
    {

        $options = [
            'option_a' => $request->input('option_a'),
            'option_b' => $request->input('option_b'),
            'option_c' => $request->input('option_c'),
            'option_d' => $request->input('option_d'),
            'option_e' => $request->input('option_e'),
        ];
        // This variable is used for comparison
        $correctAns = $request->input('is_correct_ans');

        $quiz = new Quiz($request->all());
        auth()->user()->quizzes()->save($quiz);

        foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
            $answer = new QuizAnswer;
            $answer->title = $optionValue;
            $answer->user_id = auth()->id();
            $answer->quiz_id = $quiz->id;
            if($correctAns == $optionKey){
                $answer->is_correct_ans = true;
            } else {
                $answer->is_correct_ans = false;
            }
            $answer->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

This store() method works fine, but the problem is when I attempt to update the models(both Quiz and QuizAnswers at a time):

```
    public function update(QuizRequest $request, Quiz $quiz)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
         $options = [
            'option_a' => $request->input('option_a'),
            'option_b' => $request->input('option_b'),
            'option_c' => $request->input('option_c'),
            'option_d' => $request->input('option_d'),
            'option_e' => $request->input('option_e'),
        ];
        $correctAns = $request->input('is_correct_ans');

        foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
            foreach ($quiz->answers as $answer) {
                $answer->title = $optionValue;
                $answer->user_id = auth()->id();
                $answer->quiz_id = $quiz->id;
                if($correctAns == $optionKey){
                    $answer->is_correct_ans = true;
                } else {
                    $answer->is_correct_ans = false;
                }
                $answer->save();
            }
        }

        $quiz->user_id = auth()->id();
        $quiz->title = $request->input('title');
        $quiz->explanation = $request->input('explanation');
        $quiz->lesson_id = $request->input('lesson_id');
        $quiz->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

More specifically, I am stuck inside the for loop. I can't update the answers because the inner foreach loop will update the value of all the answers with the current `$optionValue`. So if the last value of $options array is, say, 'i', I would end up with something like this in my quiz_answers table:

```
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title | is_correct_ans | user_id | quiz_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | i     |              1 |       2 |       1 | 2017-12-22 12:25:00 | 2017-12-22 17:28:44 |
|  2 | i     |              1 |       2 |       1 | 2017-12-22 12:25:00 | 2017-12-22 17:28:44 |
|  3 | i     |              1 |       2 |       1 | 2017-12-22 12:25:00 | 2017-12-22 17:28:44 |
|  4 | i     |              1 |       2 |       1 | 2017-12-22 12:25:00 | 2017-12-22 17:28:44 |
|  5 | i     |              1 |       2 |       1 | 2017-12-22 12:25:00 | 2017-12-22 17:28:44 |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Rename `is_correct_ans` to `is_correct`. When updating you need to pass id of the answer, without it you can not "update" you can only "put" (delete all current answers and create new ones). What you describe is happening because you run the inner loop 25 times - for each option in $option (5) * for each quizes answer (5). 5*5 = 25.

Comment: But the answer IS in fact being "updated". My problem is, I am unable to keep the single `answer` model in sync with the single `$optionValue`. I know why it's happening, I just don't know how I can solve it

Comment: When I store answers (throgh QuizController's store()), I can do this:
`
foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
                $answer = new QuizAnswer;
}
`
During update, I wish I could do something like this:
`
foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
    $answer = // Magically get the single answer of the quiz
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, thanks to [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$optionKey = array_keys($options);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($quiz->answers as $answer) {
        // foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
            $answer->title = $options[$optionKey[$i]];
            $answer->user_id = auth()->id();
            $answer->quiz_id = $quiz->id;
            if($correctAns == $optionKey[$i]){
                $answer->is_correct_ans = true;
            } else {
                $answer->is_correct_ans = false;
            }
            $answer->save();
            $i++;
     // }
    }
```